# Currency Interpretation for VND

Tags: bugs, units, finance

**Bug introduced in v12.2.0 or earlier, persisting through v13.2.1. Case number: 4973722**

---

As I was helping an OP with a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257197/automatic-extracting-number-from-a-text-with-given-signs) involving Vietnamese currency, I didn't realize at the time that the currency amount was not being interpreted accurately (or so I think now). Apparently, the decimal point is used as a thousands separator for VND. There are three possibilities:

- The interpretation is correct and I don't understand how their currency works.
- I am using the function incorrectly or at least missing some options.
- Or the interpreter is not working correctly for this particular currency.

For completeness sake, here is a screenshot.

[image]

**----------------------------**

Mma interprets Euros from a website text correctly; i.e., recognizes currency format:

```
astr = "MATHEMATICA kompakt: Mathematische Problemlösungen für \
Ingenieure, Mathematiker und Naturwissenschaftler

von Hans Benker | 15. Oktober 2016

4,6 von 5 Sternen 3

Kindle
29,99 € 29,99 €

Sofort lieferbar

Taschenbuch
39,99 € 39,99 €
KOSTENLOSE Lieferung";

tcases = TextCases[astr, "CurrencyAmount" -> "Interpretation"]
```

> {Quantity[29.99, "Euros"], Quantity[29.99, "Euros"], "99 € 39,99 €"}

I hope that this post reaches its correct destination.

Comment: I have flagged this as a bug, would you mind editing the post on the topline: **Bug introduced in X.X or earlier and persisting through X.X.X or later** ?

Comment: I will let senior members of the community do it. Have you heard back from WRI yet? The reason I say this is because community members run different versions and I cannot include this info as I am running v12.2.0-Win7-x64 only. Thanks for reviving this post and for your time and effort.

Comment: Sure thing, not too sure of the workflow :) Yes Wolfram have confirmed it is a bug, case number :4973722. I have included on the bottom of my post.

Comment: My bad, I failed to see your edit, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your third option is correct

> the interpreter is not working correctly for this particular currency.

and I have submitted this to Wolfram.

In general, it seems that the number separator is biased towards treating DecimalComma as a DecimalPoint, regardless of the currency (compare USD and EUR).

One would expect that [JPY](https://cashmanagement.bnpparibas.com/currency/jpy) and [VND](https://cashmanagement.bnpparibas.com/currency/vnd) get treated similarly as neither of those currencies have any decimal places

[image: VND inconsistent]

Code and other examples:

```
(* VND inconsistent*)
TextCases["$1.000.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€1.000.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥1.000.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫1.000.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

(* VND inconsistent*)
TextCases["$1,000,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€1,000,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥1,000,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫1,000,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

(* number separator is biased towards treating DecimalComma as a DecimalPoint *)
TextCases["$29,99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€29,99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥29,99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫29,99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

TextCases["$29.99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€29.99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥29.99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫29.99","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

TextCases["$29,999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€29,999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥29,999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫29,999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

TextCases["$29.999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€29.999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥29.999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫29.999","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

TextCases["$1.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€1.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥1.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫1.000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

TextCases["$1,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["€1,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["¥1,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]
TextCases["₫1,000","CurrencyAmount"->"Interpretation"]

$Version (*"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"*)
$Language (* English*)
```

---

Edit: Wolfram have confirmed it is a bug, case number :4973722